# How can I get MPC-HC x64 to play .ram files?

Tags: media-player-classic, realmedia

I have tried to play .ram files with Windows Media Player and MPC-HC x64 to no avail.  It seems the only way I can play these files is by installing Real Alternative, with its own separate instance of Media Player Classic and then use that Media player Classic to play them.

Is there a way to play the .ram files with the MPC-HC that I already have installed without having to install a separate Media Player Classic?

UPDATE: I ended up installing Real Alternative.  However, once I did that, I was able to play the .ram files with either Media Player Classic which came with Real Alternative or with MPC-HC X64.  I then uninstalled Real Alternative, and the functionality did not go away.  I guess MPC-HC was missing some codecs or something.

Comment: You can probabaly use a real alternative filter with MPC-HC and enable it to play .ram files. One lazy method is to get K-lite codec pack, standard and mega should have the filters included with MPC-HC.

Answer (score 0):

I must be a bit old fashioned as I still use MPC (non-HC), so I haven't tested this solution.

But from my reading, the 32 bit version may have better luck than the x64 version, see [codecs.forumotion](http://codecs.forumotion.net/t729-unable-to-play-very-old-ram-audio-files-in-mpc-hc-due-to-cannot-render-the-file-error).

MPC-HC should be able to play the file without installing RA+MPC:

- ['solved' ram bug report from 3 years ago](https://trac.mpc-hc.org/ticket/432)
- [File extension table](http://extension.nirsoft.net/ram)